# Why does pyspark on AWS EMR takes long time to finish?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I am running PySpark on EMR,currently just testing stuff.
Cluster size is 30 instances of m4.2xlarge

From a an s3 bucket,containing almost 10TB of logs,I am trying to get many distinct n_gram (of size 5) elements from log files,using the following code:

```
5_grams = sc.textFile(s3://my_logs_bucket)
             .map(lambda log: get_longest_first_5_gram(log))
             .distinct()
```

The function **get_longest_first_5_gram** just return the first 5 gram phrase from the log

This function takes long time to finish,because there are AWS instances that takes long time to finish - out of the 30 instances I run, about 3-4 takes lots of time to finish

Attached is an image from **Ganglia** , that represents the problem I encounter on one instance(not the master).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV8ZG.png)

Any thought on how to run this faster so it won't stuck on these instances?